# Spring Boot to multiple servers and transactions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

[image]

The picture shows two servers running the same Spring Boot JAVA API application to reduce server load. For authorization and authentication, the application uses the jwt token. Application uses jpa

Tell me how the task with transactions is solved when interacting with the database if there are several servers with the application?
If there is only one server, then there are no questions, but if there are several servers, then it is not entirely clear how this issue is resolved.

Comment: A transaction  is begun and committed on a server. The database knows which server its talking to., it's just responding to whoever called it  What is the confusing part?

Comment: In my understanding, it looks like this: the server where the application is running, and this application is engaged in transactions. The application sees how many calls are being made to the entity at a given time and, if necessary, somehow processes this matter. In cases where there are two servers on which the application runs, then the second application that runs on a completely different server does not see the first one, and if there are any manipulations with the entity in the database, this can lead to a coalition or some kind of inconsistency.

Comment: Right you need some database level locking to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture if the app is Stateless and they interact with the Database.

The database transaction is on the DB side. The transaction logic resolved by database.

So no matter number of apps.

Deep in dive in Spring read at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction

For MySQL Read more about transaction at: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch01.html